# rich text for MFC C++

Tags: c++, mfc

I have some old Rich Text files.
When I open and edit these files in Word and save it as rtf-files my C++ MFC program does not accept these files.
How to solve this problem?
Thanks
Ernst

Comment: What does 'not accept' mean? Do you get an error message? Post your code so we can help.

Comment: Does your project use UNICODE char-set? Do you use RichEdit 1.0 or RichEdit 2.0? We need to see your source code to help you out.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No I don't edit a .rc file, I edit a rtf file with word. I use Multi-Byte Character Set (and I have to!), perhaps this is the problem.

Comment: CString text;
     char c,  s[62768], *t;
     t=s;
     {  while ((c=fgetc(fp)) !=EOF)
           {  *t=c;   t++;  }
     }
     text=_T(s);  
     EDITSTREAM es = {(DWORD)&text, 0, EditStreamCallBack};
     m_myRich2.StreamIn(SF_RTF | SFF_SELECTION, es);